# Is there a way to automatically install a wordpress parent theme when installing a child theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, parent

I have a rather odd question. Is it somehow possible that when I install a child theme, to automatically install the parent theme? (Similar to TGM Plugin Activation, but for themes).

I'm asking because I have many customers who forget to install my parent theme and then contact me on how to install the theme, although I clearly explain that in the readme.txt

Answer (score 1):

When a theme is installed it is run through the [`check_parent_theme_filter()`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/theme_upgrader/check_parent_theme_filter/) function which ensures that the parent theme is installed. If it is not and it cannot be fetched from the WordPress repository then the install fails with the message keyed on `parent_theme_not_found`.

If this parent theme is not installed on the WordPress repository, you will need to use the hooks available in [`themes_api()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/themes_api/) which is the function WP uses to automatically install parent themes. The initial request is failing, however the response is passed through the `themes_api_result` filter with three arguments: `$res, $action, $args`. You can use this method as an example of the type of function that you would hook to this filter, returning `true` if you were able to successfully download and install the parent theme, `false` if it fails.

Unclear on how to hook to these using a child theme, perhaps a custom plugin would do it?

Comment: Thank you for this.

However when I install my child theme, it seems that this code is being skipped. The message I get from wordpress theme installer is this:

Unpacking the package…

Installing the theme…

This theme requires a parent theme. Checking if it is installed…

The parent theme could not be found. You will need to install the parent theme, myparenttheme, before you can use this child theme.

I'm currently looking on how to run a php code inside the function before wordpress installer runs anything else. I would have assumed init would do that.

Comment: Can't seem to find any solution to this. No matter what, Wordpress ignores the actual code during the installation.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Didn't realize that the installer would check and fail if the parent isn't there. There is a comment on [`class-wp-upgrader.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L850) that makes it look like there is a way to do this though.

Comment: Maybe check out the `themes_api_result` filter, not sure how to get code to run here though from the child theme, you mind need to have another plugin handle it?

Comment: Thanks again for the help, really appreciate it. I'm looking into themes_api_result now. However any solution that requires me to create a plugin would defeat the purpose of this task, as I am looking to have the parent theme automatically installed so my customers don't have to install 2 different things (parent & child), as many of them seem to be confused by that.